# how to determine the largest n for which one can solve within one second using an algorithm

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

So I am confused on this problem for my discrete math class, I didn't know if there was a specific formula you were supposed to use or what.
The question is "What is the largest n for which one can solve within one second a problem using an algorithm that requires f(n) bit operations, where each bit operation is carried out in 10^-6 seconds, with these functions?
a. f(n)= n^3
b. f(n)= 3^n
c. f(n)= 3^n * n^3

Answer (score 0):

You can do $10^6$ operations in a second.  The function in a takes $n^3$ operations to complete.  What is the largest $n$ for which $n^3$ is less than $10^6$?

Comment: My guess would be 10^-5?

Comment: Your guess is wrong. Try algebra instead of guess-work. Write $n^3 = 10^6$ and solve for $n$.

Comment: @gaffney would you be able to explain a little more in depth please. Also can anyone else give me an explanation?

Comment: @ bubba so n=10?

Comment: Nope. Is it true that $10^3 = 10^6$?

Comment: You need to find a number $n$ such that $n \times n \times n = 1000000$. If you can't do this, maybe you're not ready for a discrete math class.

Comment: @bubba well solving for n i got log(10^6)/log(3)

Comment: I don't know this question is pissing me off though

Comment: @rick try to guess 100

Comment: well in the end this is what i came up with 
a) n<= 10 * 10^2/3

Comment: b) 5log(10)/log(3)
c) (3X(10/3 * 10^2/3 * log(3))/ log(3)

Comment: @rick Your answer for (a) is wrong.

Comment: @gaffney a) 100